.NET Core C# mongodb driver - not able to get all the documents from collection
I know this may sound silly but I'm not getting all documents from a collection. I do a simple query using Linq and then mongo driver classes and the result is different from doing the same query via mongodb shell. I'm just beginning to use the C# mongodb driver in my .NET Core Blazor server application, and I am not an expert at this. The mongodb driver version is 2.25.
First I do a very simple Linq query:
var riesgosCollection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Riesgo_Lista>("riesgos");
var riesgosQueryableCollection = riesgosCollection.AsQueryable();
var query = riesgosQueryableCollection.Select(r => new { r.Numero });
var lista2 = await query.ToListAsync();

Then I do a simple Find:
var mongodbCollection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("riesgos");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
List<BsonDocument>? riesgos2;
riesgos2 = await mongodbCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

After doing the first (Linq) query, I get the original query, like this:
var queryTranslated = query.ToString();

And this is the string I get:
scrwebm_arsa.riesgos.Aggregate([{ "$project" : { "Numero" : "$numero", "_id" : 0 } }])

I execute this query in the mongodb shell and get, exactly, 18 documents more than the two queries I do in my .NET Core app.
This situation is just driving me crazy. I just don't even know where to start doing some research to solve this issue.
Some thoughts from you about what could be the reason something like this could be happening???
My database is in a free Atlas cluster and working fine for more than three years ...
Many thanks for your help

there is nothing related to mongo driver here. 99% that you messed up something. Since your queries have no filters, then any of the above queries regardless in the driver or in the shell should return the same data as long as you use the same connection string and collection.

check how many documents with simple count are returned in all of the cases you have, it must be the same value, if no, mostlikely you query different collections

Many thanks @dododo. Evidently I was messing things up! It was just that, while making the connection, I forgot to pass the settings to the database object. So I was actually connecting to the local db. As both dbs are so similar, I just didn't catch the mistake. It is also because I am somewhat new to c# and the mongodb driver. Thanks again.

So the mistake I was making was ...
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(mongodb_connectionString);
settings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V3;
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings); <== forgot to pass settings here! 
_mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase(mongodb_databaseName);

So the connection was against the local db.
Thanks to @dododo for guiding me in the right direction to find and fix the mistake.
